# Why does Byte Buddy lack a StackManipulation implementation corresponding to the opcode ASTORE?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

If its absence is because byte-buddy aims at the method delegation domain, then I can provide a scenario where this feature is necessary:

```
private Object invokeSpi(Object spi, Object... params) {
    Reducer reducer = (Reducer) spi;
    return reducer.reduce((Integer) params[0], (Integer) params[8]);
}
```

The above code would generate an instruction of ASTORE for the down cast statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte Buddy offers different `Instrumentation` implementations which are all composed by the mentioned `StackManipulation`s. However, no prebuilt instrumentation requires an `ASTORE` instruction which is why it is not predefned. You can however easily implement your own implementation for this purpose:

```
class AStrore implements StackManipulation {

  private final int index; // Constructor omitted

  public boolean isValid() {
    return index >= 0;
  }

  public Size apply(MethodVisitor methodVisitor, Instrumentation.Context context) {
    methodVisitor.visitIntInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, index);
    return new Size(-1, 0);
  }
}
```

Note however that you then make direct use of ASM which suffers compatbility issues. For this reason, please read the [information on Byte Buddy's website](http://bytebuddy.net) of how to repackage ASM and Byte Buddy into your own namespace.

Also note that you could avoid the `ASTORE` instruction by directly casting the instance before the call.

Comment: Thank you. I use byte-buddy in a maven plugin. So I won't suffer from the dependency issue.

Comment: Partly for using in a Maven plugin, I offer some cool new features in version 0.3 which is released some time this month. It will allow you to redefine methods of existing classes using the existing API. In general, you want to avoid the byte code API and use the high-level API. I am curious what your use case is that you need the byte code level?

Comment: as illustrated in the code in the question, to say briefly, my process is the reverse process of @AllArgument.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ByteBuddy version `1.7.3` and in that version the `ALOAD`, `ASTORE` operations along with other relevant operations can be found at in `net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.member.MethodVariableAccess`. Check out the Javadoc [here](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.7.3/net/bytebuddy/implementation/bytecode/member/MethodVariableAccess.html)